# Reflect.hasField vs anon.field

Tags: haxe

I'm writing a validation library for an API and I need to check anonymous data structures for required fields.  Is it safe to directly reference fields (`if(anon.field)...`) or will this cause problems on static targets?  Is there a speed difference between `Reflect.hasField` and direct field access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both checks have different purposes. You can do `if (anon.field == null)` if the field is already *defined*. So if the field isn't on the structure or it is uncertain (for example if you use `@:optional` fields in typedefs), you'll maybe get runtime errors.

Thats where `Reflect.hasField` comes in; it will check if it actually is defined. So if a structure has a field, you can check anything on it.

If you are targetting Javascript the `Reflect.hasField` does the same as `Object.hasOwnProperty`.

> Reflect Api docs: http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#hasField